# Why is there grid lines for some plots and not for others?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plot-grid

Consider this MWE,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.style.use('classic')
pyplot.rcParams.update( {
    'text.usetex': True,
    "font.family": "serif",
    'text.latex.preamble': r'\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mlmodern}', } )
import numpy


fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(3,3)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1,
    left=0.09, right=.95, top=.95, bottom=.09)

x = numpy.linspace(0, 8, 100)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        ax[i,j].plot(x, numpy.sin((1+j)*x+numpy.pi*i), )
        ax[i,j].grid(which='both')  # <----------------- I added grid here
        if i!=2: ax[i,j].set_xticks([])
        if j==1: ax[i,j].set_yticks([])
        if j==2: ax[i,j].yaxis.tick_right()

ax[0,0].set_ylabel('$\phi=0$')
ax[1,0].set_ylabel('$\phi=\pi$')
ax[2,0].set_ylabel('$\phi=2\pi$')

ax[2,0].set_xlabel('$f = 1$')
ax[2,1].set_xlabel('$f = 2$')
ax[2,2].set_xlabel('$f = 3$')

pyplot.savefig('waves.png')
```

Which produces the following plot,
[image: waves with varying freq and phase]

I don't understand why matplotlib has grid lines for (0,0) and (0,2) axes, vertical grid lines for axes (0,1), horizontal grid lines for axes (1,0), (1,2), (2,0) and (2,2) and no grid lines for axes (1,1) and (2,1).

How do I make sure that all axes have the grid similar to (0,0)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to removing the ticks. Instead you could just remove the tick **labels**.

Replace:

```
        if i!=2: ax[i,j].set_xticks([])
        if j==1: ax[i,j].set_yticks([])
```

with:

```
        if i!=2: ax[i,j].set_xticklabels([])
        if j==1: ax[i,j].set_yticklabels([])
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't need the labels on the right, note that you could automatically hide the inner labels by setting `sharex=True, sharey=True`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1,
    left=0.09, right=.95, top=.95, bottom=.09)

x = numpy.linspace(0, 8, 100)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        ax[i,j].plot(x, numpy.sin((1+j)*x+numpy.pi*i), )
        ax[i,j].grid(which='both')
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Also, for letting me know about `sharex` and `sharey`. Do you know why my background is not gray like yours?

Comment: @sigsegv I don't know. I use matplotlib 3.8.2 if you want to compare.

Comment: I am using v3.8.2

Comment: Do you manage to change it manually? `fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')`

Comment: I had it grey when using `pyplot.show()` but it was white with `savefig` like in your code @sigsegv

Comment: Then that must be it since I have used the notebook figure and did not export it

Comment: With the `sharex`/`sharey` solution, you can get the right labels back with `if j==2: ax[i,j].tick_params('y', labelright=True)`

Comment: @RuthC that's a good point. Feel free to edit this in the answer if you like (I'll do it later otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this two lines

```
if i!=2: ax[i,j].set_xticks([])
if j==1: ax[i,j].set_yticks([])
```

because you are removing the ticks and not just the text. To solve it you need to use ticklabels instead of ticks as:

```
if i!=2: ax[i,j].set_xticklabels([])
if j==1: ax[i,j].set_yticklabels([])
```